# How to charge using stripe v2 with custom form with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I keep getting

> Stripe::InvalidRequestError in ChargesController#create
>   Customer cus_8fqEmSUxnGEO6g does not have a linked source with ID tok_18OUXYLM1r6OYriq1WcKNB79.

I'm not sure what is causing this.

Here is my form:

```
 <%= form_tag charges_path, id:"payment-form" do %>
    <article>
      <label class="amount">
        <span>Price: <%= number_to_currency @booking.price %></span>
      </label>
    </article>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'booking_id', @booking.id %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
      <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil, data: {stripe: "number"}, value:"4242 4242 4242 4242", class:"form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVC)" %>
      <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil, data: {stripe: "cvc"}, value:"123", class:"form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration" %>
      <%= text_field_tag :card_month, nil, name: nil, data: {stripe: "exp"}, value:"12 / 17", class:"form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="card-errors">
    </div>
    <%= submit_tag 'Submit', class: "button round", id: "pay_now", class:"btn btn-success" %>

  <% end %>
```

Here is my controller:

```
    class ChargesController < ApplicationController
      before_action :authenticate_user!

      def create
         token = params[:stripeToken]
         # Amount in cents
         @amount = (current_booking.price * 100).to_i

         customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
         :email => params[:stripeEmail]
         )

         charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
         :customer    => customer.id,
         :amount      => @amount,
         :description => 'Content',
         :currency    => 'usd',
         :source      => token
         )

         redirect_to booking_path(current_booking), notice:"Thanks, your  purchase was successful!"
         rescue Stripe::CardError => e
         flash[:error] = e.message
         redirect_to "/bookings/new/?space_listing_id=#{@current_booking.space_listing_id}"
         end

          private

          def current_booking
            @current_booking ||= Booking.find(params[:booking_id])
          end
        end
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#payment-form').submit(function(event) {
    var $form = $(this);
// Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $form.find('#pay_now').prop('disabled', true);

Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

// Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
return false;
  });
});

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
  var $form = $('#payment-form');

  if (response.error) {
    $("div.card-errors").text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('#pay_now').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
// response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
     var token = response.id;
// Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server  
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
// and submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
   }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a charge for a customer, the `source` parameter would represent a card that's already linked to that customer object:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/#create_charge-source

In this case you're attempting to pass a token that's not yet associated with that customer (which is rightly failing). Instead, you'll need to either create or update the customer object with that source before attempting to make the charge. To fix this, you'll really only need to move the `:source => token` from the charge creation attempt to the customer:

```rb
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
  :email => params[:stripeEmail],
  :source => token.id
)
```

There's a guide on Stripe's site that covers this in more detail:
https://stripe.com/docs/charges#saving-credit-card-details-for-later